# Would the use of nepomuk be allowed in the app developer contest?

Tags: application-development

Ive recently switched to the platform and don't remember if installed it or it came with the system. Would Nepomuk be considered part of the allowed packages?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the necessary packages are available in the standard Ubuntu archives you can use them.  There appear to be many nepomuk related packages there, so as long as you only need those your application would qualify.